# JPA 2 + Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

```
Employee (table)
id - int
ctd_id - int
message - char

SELECT a.*
FROM Employee a left outer join 
( select * from Employee where message = 23 ) b
on a.ctd_id = b.ctd_id
where a.message = 22 and b.id is null;
```

This is what i tried

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteria = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> emp = criteria.from(Employee.class); 
CriteriaQuery<Employee> sq = c.select(emp);  

Subquery<Employee> sq2 = criteria.subquery(Employee.class); 
Root<Employee> emp2 = sq2.from(Employee.class); 
Join<Employee,Employee> sqEmp = emp2.join("ctd_id", JoinType.LEFT); 
sq.select(sqemp).where(cb.equal(emp2.get("message"), cb.parameter(String.class, "23"))); 

sq.where(cb.in(path).value(sq2));
TypedQuery<Employee> q = em.createQuery(criteria);
List<Employee> employeess = q.getResultList()
```

But, i am not able to understand as to how i should apply a join on a subquery with where clause.

please help .

Comment: What have you done so far? And what's exactly your Problem? You may should read a Criteria Tutorial like [Dynamic, typesafe queries in JPA 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/) and come back with more specific questions other than "please do my work". Maybe it would be a good Idea if you also read the [ask] page.

Comment: edited my question, and included snippets of what i tried.

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not support sub-queries in the FROM clause.

Either use SQL for your query, or rewrite it not to have a sub-query in the from clause, it doesn't look like you need it.